# How to put a column from a database table into a dynamic list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, code-first

For my Project I want to access the database especially one table which has the **BauTeilId** in it and putting all the **BauTeilId** into one List in the Controller

---

DefaultConnection:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=QualitätsKontrolleDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

---

**Controller**
The String **Code** is from the HTML and consits of 6 digits

```
private ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult StartPage(string Code)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Code);

            var list = Context.Result.All(c => c.BauTeilId);
            return View();
        }
```

---

**Table used for this**
I only need the **BauTeilId**
TypenID         int
PruefungenID        int
BildID          int
BauTeilID       string
Date            DateTime
xLabel          string
X           int
YLabel          string
Y           int
FehlerCode      string
Fehlername      string
FehlerGruppe1       string
FehlerGruppe2       string
Result          int

---

Right now the output is not existent but it should be the whole column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If to want to get only BauTeilId   from table like`select BauTeilId  from table` use

```
(from t in Context.Result
 select new {
  t.BauTeilId
 }).toList();  // .toList(); is not necessary, Linq returns an `IEnumerable `
```

That LINQ Statement,Hope you get point.

Answer (score 0):

You can take list of any columns you want like this :

```
var myDynamicList = Context.Result.Select(c=> new { c.BauTeilId }).ToList();
```

this will be a List of dynamic type. For example you can call first element BauTeilId like this :

```
myDynamicList.First().BauTeilId;
```